# Can someone explain countability and cardinality simply?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

One of the questions in my book asked: Show that the set $\Bbb Z^+ \times \Bbb Z^+$ is countable.?

Now I don't want the solution to this particular problem, rather how to go about solving these types of problems. What if it was $\Bbb Q^+\times \Bbb Q^+$ or some other thing etc. etc.

To start of to show countability you have show it is cardinal (ie it is one-to-one and onto), but then what?

Thank you so much! I have an exam tomorrow and am very lost, the book is not helping.

Comment: Apply the [Cantor-Shröder-Berstein Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem). Usually one of the injections is trivial and the other requires a bit of thought.

Comment: @GitGud That is way beyond my levels of understanding. Sorry. Maybe if you don't mind (could you walk through my example step by step.. . I know my question did not ask that).

Comment: If you can't use that theorem (yet), then you're not supposed to use it. It is very powerful, so you are probably required to find bijections on a case by cases basis for practice. In any case what the Cantor-Shröder-Berstein Theorem says is very intuitive. If there is an injection from $X$ to $Y$, then, in some sense, $X$ has fewer (or equal) elements than $Y$. If there is an injection from $Y$ to $X$, then, similarly, $Y$ has fewer (or equal) elements than $X$. Thus $X\leq _c\land Y\leq _cX$ and $X=_c Y$.

Comment: I'm not sure the C-S-B theorem is relevant.  What is your definition of countable?

Comment: @TrevorWilson  A set is called countable if and only if it is finite or countably infinite (If it has the same cardinality as the set of positive integers Z+)

Comment: I see.  In that case Git Gud's comment is relevant.  However, it may also be useful to note that a set $X$ is countable if and only if there is an injection of $X$ into $\mathbb{Z}^+$.  (Sometimes this is easier to check.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess in the general case there is probably no other way then to find an explicit injection in either direction to/from $\Bbb N$. But in a simple case like this you can prove it graphically (I think this prove came originally from Cantor):

Write the elements of $\Bbb Z^+\times \Bbb Z^+$ in an infinite square, starting in the upper left. Now count the elements on each diagonal starting from the upper left, thereby associating each element with an element from $\Bbb N$. In this way you can associate each element of your square with an element of $\Bbb N$.

This works in a similar way for $\Bbb Q$ or all kinds of finite cartesian products of countable sets.

(Note that this construction even finds a Bijection between $\Bbb N$ and the given set, even though in the general case its enough to find an injection for both directions.)